# Can't deploy app because of database connection error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cloudcontrol, ruby-2.1

does anyone know why I can't deploy my application? I'm using the exact same configuration/changes I did to my other app which I can deploy to cc without any problems (different credentials, of course).

`database.yml`:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  reconnect: false
  pool: 3
  database: xxx
  host: horton.elephantsql.com
  port: 5432
  username: xxx
  password: xxx
```

This is the error message I get:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   could not connect to server: Connection refused
   Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
   /srv/tmp/builddir/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `initialize'
   /srv/tmp/builddir/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `new'
   /srv/tmp/builddir/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `connect'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since during push the Add-on credentials are not yet available (they're only available during run-time) you have to set the following option to tell Rails to not try to initialize the database during asset precompilation.

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false if ENV['BUILDPACK_RUNNING']
```

You can find this and other Rails related settings here: https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Guides/Ruby/RubyNotes.

Comment: Thanks but I do have that code snippet already in my `application.rb`:
`config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false if ENV['BUILDPACK_RUNNING']`

Any other idea?